# contact form won't send

Tags: php, html, forms

I found this code here on Stackoverlow but I can't get it to work. It reacts fine when I hit the Submit, but I don't recieve any mails.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "email@example.com"; // this is your Email address
    $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $subject = "Form submission";
    $subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
    $message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
    echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $first_name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
    // You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to another page.
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Form submission</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="post">
First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name"><br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
Message:<br><textarea rows="5" name="message" cols="30"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Anyone who can help me. I should maybe say I use Joomla, if that has something to do with it? .. and of course I changed the `$to` to my email ;)

Comment: You need to setup a mail server in order to send emails. gmail has one and you can use it for free.

Answer (score 0):

I have check your code, it looks good.
If you check your code on **Localhost**, you have to use `SMTP` to send an emails or enable `SMTP` in **JOOMLA**

If you are try this code on server, please check that your service provider support `PHP` mail in order to send an emails. if they are not allow you have to contact **host service provider** and/ or use `SMTP` mail server

Comment: I changed it to smtp in Joomla settings, send out a test-mail and got it right away. So why won't the form send ? :(

Comment: Because your form is not built-in Joomla, it's html form. Your email should use smtp email to send email.